# JMeter does not record any client server activity

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I am trying to record any client-server activity in JMeter as a start for learning. I am doing this from a company network and hence have to go through proxy. Below are the steps I took for recording.

- I read in JMeter documentation that for recording through proxy I have to invoke from command by giving the proper proxy. I used below code to invoke JMeter.

  jmeter -H "*proxy address taken from Internet settings*" -P "8080" -u "*Domain**UserName*" -a "*password*".

  With this JMeter invokes fine and then I start the normal process of creating a thread group and a recording controller.
- Now I am changing the internet setting in IE to local host and mentioning the port as given in JMeter (8080). I am keeping the proxy used as it is because without proxy no site will open except for the internal company sites.
- Also I have imported the certificate which JMeter uses for the browsers.

Comment: Try using [Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension).

Comment: sorry. forgot to add the major issue. :)

Comment: Even after doing all this JMeter is not recording any client server traffic. I am just trying a normal hit by doing google.com.

Comment: Did you follow [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)?

Comment: I am going through this now. Will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is now resolved**

I added : *JAVA_HOME* variable in User environment variables with value pointing to jre installed on my machine *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre*

Also I had to select *Java* under *HTTP Sampler Setting* in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. (Though I don't get the purpose of this setting).

[HTTP Sampler setting changed to *Java*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIUsc.png)

After doing above changes script is recording fine under company proxy.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to consider to use [chrome extension for jMeter script recording](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/record-and-edit-jmeter-script-without-using-jmeter-blazemeters-chrome-extension) without launching JMeter benefits: You can export the script written to JMeter and/or to cloud as well and run it on the cloud.

Comment: Yes. I tried that now. But again when I run the script (created by Blazemeter) I get the connection refused error.

Comment: Could it be a problem if I don't have a JDK and only JRE?